# Add Crosshair to Bing Maps WPF Control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, bing-maps

I would like to add a crosshair with a smaller circle around it to my Bing Maps WPF Control. This is due to Restrictions (WinForms-Application with Wrapper around the WPF-Control) only possible in the Code-Behind and not in the XAML
It should look like:
[image: crosshair]

I followed the Instruction as decribed in [Adding Shapes to the Map](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh868034.aspx) on MSDN, but this only described how i can add a Shape based on a Location, but it should be centered on the Control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the image directly to the map without setting it's position. Do something like this:

```
var img = new Image();
//Add code to load your image.

//Center image some how. Try margins, or hortizontal and vertical alignment.
image.Margin = new Thickness(map.ActualWidth - img.ActualWidth, map.ActualHeight - img.ActualHeight);

map.Children.Add(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh868032.aspx It shows how to add an image to the map at a specified location from code behind.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer, but i want to add the image to the center of the control and not at a specific location. I could remove the image and readd it to the center every time the viewpoint of the map is changed, but should not there be a easier way?